# Strange graphical glitch when booting into Windows 11

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, windows-11

I've been having this strange problem for a while. Every other day when I boot up the computer, I see a black screen. Despite the black screen, the monitor seems to work fine and when I log into windows "blindly" by hitting enter and entering password. The desktop looks like as follows (black parts appear on different places between sessions):

[image]

I have a dual monitor setup; My main monitor (the picture above) is attached to GTX 970 and my second monitor to the Intel's graphics.

[image]

I usually check the event logs afterwards, and find the following recurring error:

> Log Name:      System Source:        nvlddmkm Date:
> 12/26/2023 07:34:56 Event ID:      0 Task Category: None Level:
> Error Keywords:      Classic User:          N/A Computer:
> Blacklynx Description: The description for Event ID 0 from source
> nvlddmkm cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event
> is not installed on your local computer or the installation is
> corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local
> computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
> had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> \Device\Video3 Resetting TDR occurred on GPUID:100
>
> The message resource is present but the message was not found in the
> message table
>
> Event Xml: 
>
>
> 0
> 0
> 2
> 0
> 0
> 0x80000000000000
>
> 77416
>
>
> System
> Blacklynx
>       
> \Device\Video3
> Resetting TDR occurred on GPUID:100
> 00000000020030000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Appearently it has something to do with the nvidia card or the nvidia's display driver. Which makes me wonder if the problem is indeed with GTX 970, why do I experience the same issue on the secondary monitor connected to another GPU?

But today I noticed something very strange, as it shows in the picture a portion of picture marked on the main monitor is also shown on the secondary monitor several times.

[image]

Other than this strange issue, during daily usage there hasn't been any problems and this issue is usually fixed upon restart until it shows up again randomly in the subsequent boots.

So far I tested the RAMs using Windows 11's built in memory checker and no issues were reported.

My system specs are as follows:

- **CPU:** Intel Core i7 4790k
- **GPU:** Gigabyte GTX 970 (GV-N970G1 GAMING-4GD
- **MB:** Asus Maximus Hero VII
- **RAMs:** 2x16GB G.Skill 667hz + 2x16GB Samsung 800hz
- **OS**: Windows 11 Pro 22H2
- **Display driver version:** 546.17

Thanks in advance for taking time to read this question, I'm looking forward to your answers.

Comment: [Seems to be a lot about this on the Internet.](https://www.google.com/search?q=Resetting%20TDR%20occurred%20on%20GPUID%3A100) One thing seems to be permanently switching to the nvidia graphics: https://hardforum.com/threads/error-reset-tdr-occurred-on-gpuid-4090-gigabyte-oc.2023163/post-1045498748 though I'd wonder if it might be something about the power plan. Try changing the power plan to high performance https://www.elevenforum.com/t/change-power-plan-settings-in-windows-11.6918/ or check the actual plan settings and try changing PCI Express Power saving off.